# C#.net Core 6.0 web app connecting to Snowflake from Azure using RSA key in file

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

I need to connect my .Net Core 6.0 web app from Azure to snowflake. I have RSA key stored locally and in the connection string it is referenced:

SnowflakeDbCon": "account=**************;authenticator=snowflake_jwt;user=xxxxxxxx;private_key_file=c:\Keys\rsa_key.p8;private_key_pwd=yyyyyyyyy;db=dbbbbbbb;schema=MY_SCHEMA;"

Code:
builder.Services.AddScoped(_=>
new SnowflakeDbConnection { ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SnowflakeDbCon") });

This works as expected. But I need to deploy to Azure and I am not sure how the key file path in Azure in the connection string will work.
I tried removing the key file path reference and adding the key file to the project
private_key_file=rsa_key.p8
this works locally, but fails in Azure with the error
Could not find file 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\rsa_key.p8'

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

> this works locally, but fails in Azure with the error Could not find
> file 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\rsa_key.p8'

You change path from `C:\home\site\wwwroot\` to  `D:\home\site\wwwroot` and add rsa_key.p8 in this path `D:\home\site\wwwroot\` by using following steps.

1. Go to Azure porta.
2. Click on Application.
3. In left hand side menu search `Advance Tools` and select its.

[image]

4. Open new window. On top menu select Debug console drop down and select CMD.

[image]

5. Open Console panel select Site->wwwroot-> create p8 file here. Click + icon and add file.

[image]

6. After adding rsa_key.p8
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

These steps helped me create the key file and upload to the \wwwroot folder! TY

As a side note, I has to change Deployment method to Zip Deploy.